# How to install adobe flash tar?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, tar, adobe-flash

I have a problem getting Flash working in Mint13 XFCE.

Now I have downloaded the tar file, but I don't understand what I have to do to get this installed.

I have this file:

install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar

downloaded from here: http://get.adobe.com/nl/flashplayer/?no_redirect

How do I install this?

Answer (score 2):

Extract the readme.txt from the tar file you downloaded and read the instructions in there:

```
Installing using the plugin tar.gz:
  o Unpack the plugin tar.gz and copy the files to the appropriate location.  
  o Save the plugin tar.gz locally and note the location the file was saved to.
  o Launch terminal and change directories to the location the file was saved to.
  o Unpack the tar.gz file.  Once unpacked you will see the following:
        + libflashplayer.so
        + /usr
  o Identify the location of the browser plugins directory, based on your Linux 
    distribution and Firefox version
  o Copy libflashplayer.so to the appropriate browser plugins directory.
    At the prompt type:
        + cp libflashlayer.so <BrowserPluginsLocation>
  o Copy the Flash Player Local Settings configurations files to the /usr 
    directory.  At the prompt type:
        + sudo cp -r usr/* /usr
```

Comment: Where things go depend on your Linux distribution and version of Firefox. Mine (Ubuntu 12.04) is in `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/` The directory is copied recursively, *as indicated in the readme.txt* over `/usr` which puts the files underneath `usr` in their respective subdirs there. You do not put the directory `usr` itself somewhere as `/usr` already exists.

Comment: I found the libflashplayer.so directory. I pasted the new file there using cp -r command. i used this command `sudo cp -r usr/* /usr` where I changed `usr/*` into `/home/<username>/Downloads/usr` Is this wrong? I copied the files in the wrong directory now? How can I find the directory I should paste the files is? using `find / -name libflashplayer.so -print` I found the location of this file is `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so` Should the directories under /usr be pasted in this location?

Comment: @DutchArjo Why are you not following the exact instructions? You should definitely not paste (or copy or move) anything from `/usr` to anywhere. You have to unpack/extract (with `tar xf <filename>`)  the tar archive. I would always, without exception do so, in an **empty** directory and in that directory do `cp -r usr/* /usr`.

Comment: @DutchArjo no, the `libflashlayer.so` should be copied to `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/` but it looks like it's already there(?). Then, the files in the subdirectory `usr/` if wherever you extracted the tar file to should be copied to `/usr`. You should run the exact command provided by the readme: `sudo cp  -r usr/* /usr`.

Comment: maybe my comment was not very clear. I did unpack the archive and followed the exact instructions in the readme file. I extracted the tar file to `/home/<username>/Downloads/` then I had to found the default plugin directory and I found a site which helped me to do so. I used the command in the readme file to put the .so file in the right directory: `At the prompt type: + cp libflashlayer.so <BrowserPluginsLocation>` and after that I used `sudo cp -r usr/* /usr`  to copy the file to the right location (I only changed the first location as the path is different as I explained)